Nuget package manager and chocolaty
I have one .exe and one powerhsell script that execute that .exe.
And now I want to make nuget package. When I runt the nuget package it automatically run the powerhsell script and results execute the exe as well.
Any idea how to proceed
I thoof using choclate to call the .nupkg
